# How to correctly get post type in a the_title filter

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, title, actions

I want to prepend text to the post titles of a specific custom post type, but the filter below didn't work. Instead of changing only that CPT's post titles, it changed *all* titles on the given CPT's pages—menus items, posts in secondary loops, etc.

What am I doing wrong? I'm guessing it's something to do with the scope of get_post_type().

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_cpt_prefix' );

function add_cpt_prefix( $title ) {
    if ( get_post_type() == 'press' ) {
        $title = '<span>Press:</span> ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can exclude menus by testing the post id :

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_cpt_prefix' );

function add_cpt_prefix( $title ) {
    global $id, $post;
    if ( $id && $post && $post->post_type == 'press' ) {
        $title = '<span>Press:</span> ' . $title;
    }
    return $title;
}
```

Comment: Checking for $id does the trick.

Comment: Checking for $id only seems to work in some cases, not all. See @dotancohen's answer for a modern solution.

Answer (score 7):

You can globalize `$post` to work out the post type.

**Example:**

```
add_filter( 'the_title', 'add_the_title_prefix' );

function add_the_title_prefix( $title ) 
{
    global $post;
    if ( 'custom_post_type_name' != $post->post_type )
        return $title;

    return "<span>Press:</span> {$title}";
}
```

Comment: 2 more edits and it is a communtiy wiki ;)

Comment: This causes all menu items on press posts to get "Press: " prepended. (The menu is a standard Wordpress menu.)

Comment: then use the `add_filter` just before your loop, and add `remove_filter` after the loop

Answer (score 3):

In the years since this question has been added, the `$id` parameter has been added to the `the_title` action hook. So now you can **get the post type easily using `get_post_type()`** as so:

```
function actionTheTitle($title, $id)
{
    $post_type = get_post_type($id);

    // Clever code here

    return $title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was not with get_post_type() like I thought, so Bainternet's suggestion of $post->post_type produced the same results.  Bainternet's suggestion from the comments was what was needed:

> use the add_filter just before your loop, and add remove_filter after the loop