# How to append text to title of Custom Post Type post (without affecting all titles on page)?

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development

This question '[How to correctly get post type in a the_title filter](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/26115/how-to-correctly-get-post-type-in-a-the-title-filter)' is exactly what I'm trying to achieve.  I have set a filter as below but it affects all titles on the page (in the menu, sidebar and footer) rather than just the post title.

Apparently I need to use the `add_filter` just before the loop and add `remove_filter` after the loop, but I'm not sure how to do this.  I'm developing a plugin and am looking for a solution that does not involve making any changes in theme/template files.

Love to hear any and all suggestions.  Thanks

```
function custom_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    $text = 'Extra text: ';

    if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'custom_post_type' ){
        return $text . $title;
    }
    else {
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_title', array($this, 'custom_title' ) );
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe checking `in_the_loop` will work for the main query:

```
function custom_title( $title ) {
    global $post;
    $text = 'Extra text: ';

    if ( get_post_type( $post->ID ) == 'custom_post_type' && in_the_loop() ){
        return $text . $title;
    }
    else {
        return $title;
    }
}

add_filter( 'the_title', array($this, 'custom_title' ) );
```

Comment: Thank you so much - that works beautifully!  I've just added that second condition to the rest of my function and am very happy now :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe an easier way

```
if ( $post->post_type == 'custom_post_type' )
```